# Windows Server 2003 disk queue length problem

Tags: windows, file-sharing, hard-drive

I am using a server 2003 as a file server what support 30-40 user simultaneously.

Users always report the response time of open folder is very slow and something will cause the explorer. I check the **disk queue length** using performance monitor, it always keep at full(100) level.

Is there are any way to check what caused the issue and how to fix it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try using Process Explorer (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to see what process thats eating up your I/O.

Comment: I just check the I/O by processxp, here is the information

Order by the most consuming

I/O Reads
1. System
2&3 explorer.exe

I/O Read Bytes
1. lsass.exe
2. spoolsv.exe

I/O Write
1. System
2. lsass.exe

I/O Write Bytes
1. System
2. spoolsv.exe

Comment: Hmm.. so no applications eating up I/O then. How much RAM does the server have? Please enter ctrl+i in the process explorer and report back Total physical memory, Aviable and System Cache.